# Elliptic,hyperbolic and parabolic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

For  the following linear second order PDEs, the task is to identify in what regions of the two-dimensional plane the equation is elliptic, hyperbolic, or parabolic.

$$\sin(xy) u_{xx}\ -6 u_{xy}\ +u_{yy}\ =0$$

I began by composing the discriminant $\Delta^2 = B^2 -4AC$

$-1 \le \sin(xy) \le 1$

$32 \le 36-4\sin(xy) \le 40$

Then it is hyperbolic in the whole domain. Is that correct? And how I can sketch that in two dimensions?

Comment: This is correct. It is just the whole $xy$-domain. So no need to sketch anything.